# wms layer not shown on geoserver while wfs works fine

Tags: geoserver

I have a really strange problem which I don't know how to solve.
I have shp file I've import into PostGIS using PostGIS Loader (made sure the srs is 4326 same is shp file) .

In geoserver (2.6.1) I've created a postgres store and published the table I've imported , set it SRS (WGS84) and style (default Polygon).

Now this is where things go weird and I have no idea how to approach this problem:

1. If I Preview the layer via WFS (KML/GeoJson/CSV etc...) I get the txt files with all features inside.
2. If I try to preview via openlayers or any other WMS (like geotiff) either I see empty map or get error
3. When I create a store of shp files with the data I've imported , it shows fine as wms.

Here is example that I do see features via wfs (csv) but error in wms.

Any idea ?!

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
It was pointed out in comments that "width=78450&height=330" is a strange size (although this is what geoserver auto generate in preview) so I've manually edited the request to :

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Oakland/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Oakland:oakland180110&styles=&bbox=-122.502975463867,37.3532028198242,-121.66429901123,37.9185791015625&width=512&height=345&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image/png
```

and now I get empty image:
[image]

Since I do see the data in the shp files preview :

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Oakland/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Oakland:Oakland180110&styles=&bbox=-122.491314021,37.379831195000065,-121.71847960399995,37.89508712800005&width=512&height=341&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng
```

I tend to think that the problem is somewhere from reading the data from PostGIS.

[image]

Last thing I did is comparing the shp layer settings to the postgis layer settings but I don't see anything that might hint on the problem I have:

[image]

**Update 2:**

I've checked geoserver log and noticed that the following query returns null:

```
SELECT encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Simplify(ST_Force_2D("the_geom"), 0.002246433788820923)),'base64') as "the_geom" FROM datatable
```

Now , the_geom column is geometry type and is not null . 
When running ST_Simplify it brings back null :

This is working :

```
SELECT ST_Force_2D("the_geom") as "the_geom" FROM "public"."datatable"
```

This brings the nulls :

```
SELECT ST_Simplify(ST_Force_2D("the_geom"), 0.002246433788820923) as "the_geom" FROM "public"."datatable"
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: "width=78450&height=330" That seems like a strange size to request, but it isn't inconsistent with your BBOX. It seems weird though that your BBOX is a slim area from 0 to 127W. Perhaps the request is malformed, or some null geometry snuck into your shapefile.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , based on it I've updated my question with more information

Comment: Can you find a reason for why the bounding box between the shapefile and the postgis layer are a little off? Have you tried re-computing them, and forcing the shape file native SRS to 4326.  Also, your data looks like multipolgyons in the csv, but renders more like points in one of those screenshots.

Comment: I will delete and import again.

Comment: Well , It appears this happens on all of my PostGIS tables... so either there is problem in my geoserver version or something screwed in the database (8 different databases.. hard to believe)

Comment: Are you using shp2pgsql-gui via the pgadminIII plugin to load everything?

Comment: I'm using "PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export manager" that came with PostGIS 2.0 installation.

Comment: Your format=image/png needs to be escaped: format=image%2Fpng. That is likely what produced the white map.

Comment: That is not the problem , same url works on different machine with older geoserver

Comment: URL escaping is possibly browser sensitive. Otherwise, what is shown in the geoserver logs?

Comment: Try setting the srs to 4326 not Wgs84, which may change the axis order. Failing that check the log file

Comment: Set GeoServer logging into geotools developer level and you should see the actual SQL that is sent to PostGIS. I would also check that some reasonable style is attached to your layer, though the default styles usually work and render the features with some visible style.

Comment: I've just tested again ,different tables work fine , I think the problem might be that I created empty db (without postgis 2 support) and restored spatial database to it. maybe thats the problem. will do more testing as suggested and will let you all know.

Comment: @user30184 - I've found the problem but I don't know the cause. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've finally found the solution , needs to remove from the store definition the checkbox on "Support on the fly geometry simplification"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this is to remove the checkbox from the store definition :
[image]